# Exact Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP) solution in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

Is there an algorithm to solve the (time-indepenedent) TSP problem exactly (no heuristics, nodes are not points in space and costs are arbitrary) in polynomial time?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of asking, you could have read the first sentence of the Wikipedia article.

Comment: This probably should be moved to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Lther: Nope. Off topic on cstheory.

Comment: Genetic algorithms are pretty good at finding a good solution to TSP almost instantly if you can handle the solution only being "near perfect". In real life situations this is usually a great tradeoff: http://www.lalena.com/ai/tsp/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. It is considered NP-Hard.

If you do find one, tell me (in secret of course) and we'll be rich together :-)

I know Wikipedia can be often wrong, but you might find their page on TSP interesting:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Answer (score 4):

Probably not. It is [NP-hard](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/NP-hard).

Answer (score 3):

If NP=P then the answer is yes, it can be done in polynomial time.  If NP≠P, then the answer is no, it cannot be done in polynomial time.  NP=P vs. NP≠P is an open problem, though I suspect you'll find that a representative sample of those sufficiently familiar with the issue will have more people who believe NP≠P than who believe NP=P.

Answer (score 2):

No!, to polynomial time. 
Yes!, to there is an exact algorithm.